# How to edit this simple function to correctly sort letters and words in list alphabetically (Python)?

Tags: python, list, function

The objective is to take a list of strings, sort the letters in each string,
and then sort the full list. We want to modify the list in place (so, use `sort()` rather than `sorted()`).

My function:

```
def string_lst(lst):
        return lst.sort()
```

So, this means I would expect:

```
string_lst(["bdb", "acb"])
```

To return `"abc", "bbd"`

This doesn't work though. Can anyone suggest how to amend this function to achieve the desired output?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.
Your problem clearly describes two levels of sorting; your function clearly has only one.

Comment: letters only sort based on the first letter so you get "acb" first and then "bdb" , if same letters occur it shifts to second letter etc...

Comment: @ombk yes - can you suggest whether there's something that would organise letters within a string beforehand?

Comment: what are you allowed to use for the function?

Comment: Do you mean what's the input? Just a single list which contains strings (assume letters only)

Comment: Your function returns None because lst.sort() updates lst and doesn’t give a value. So actually you need to use sorted(lst)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's divide the problem into 2 parts: sorting a string and sorting a list of strings.

The first part:
There is no direct method for sorting strings in python. But we can use `sorted`, which accepts iterable as an argument and returns sorted list of items of iterable:

```
>>> s = 'bace'   
>>> sorted(a)
['a','b','c','e']
```

We can `join` that list to get sorted string:

```
>>>sorted_a = ''.join(sorted(a))
>>>sorted_a
'abce'
```

So we can write this for the first part:

```
def sort_list(list_of_strings):
    for i in range(len(list_of_strings)):
        list_of_strings[i] = ''.join(sorted(list_of_strings[i]))
```

The second part is easy, there is `sort` method for sorting lists and we will use that. Final result:

```
def sort_list(list_of_strings):
    for i in range(len(list_of_strings)):
        list_of_strings[i] = ''.join(sorted(list_of_strings[i]))
    list_of_strings.sort()
    return list_of_strings
```

Edit: You don't actually need to return list. The list you passed as parameter is "updated". But if you call this function like `sort_list(["aef","eghab"])`, then you need to assign this function to another variable to retrieve sorted list

Comment: Thanks! But when we use an input, e.g. ["hi", "ab"], the output is 'None' rather than what we'd expect. Do you know why?

Comment: I thought you wanted to sort list inplace. You get `None` because this function doesn't return anything. You

Comment: That's true, I do want to edit in place - I just assumed you'd be able to view the result of the rearrangment of the strings. Is this possible too to check that the result is correct? E.g. by adding `return`?

Comment: I added, you can check it